# No start problem

Tags: electrical, starting

I packed the car for about 4 to 5 weeks without driving it but it was still in good condition.so after that when I try to start the car it only cranked but won't run the engen until now I do not know else to do.I am therefore asking for your help on this issue.I changed engen speed sensor but it does not make any change.I checked petrol its enough and it also reaches the engen.

Comment: Its peugeot 307 2002 model with 1.9 cc engen capacity.

Comment: I see Peugeot 307 models with 1.6 and 2.0 petrol engines, and others with 1.6 and 2.0 diesel engines. But I see no 1.9 motors. Is the motor petrol or diesel?